# CollectionViewSource.Source = DomainDataSource Error

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services, collectionviewsource

I'm attempting to set the source of a CollectionViewSource to a DomainDataSource:

```
<navigation:Page.Resources>

    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding ElementName=myDataSource, Path=Data}"/>

</navigation:Page.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

    <ria:DomainDataSource Name="myDataSource" QueryName="MyGetQuery" AutoLoad="True">
        <ria:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
            <ds:MyDataContext/>
        </ria:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
    </ria:DomainDataSource>
```

I am getting this error message when the page loads:

"Unsupported type of source for a collection view."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't connect to "Data" path. Try connecting to a subitem. For example I have an `Entity<A>` that has an association to `Entity<B>`.

if "MyGetQuery" returns me EntitySet then I can use CollectionViewSource as such:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding ElementName=myDataSource, Path=Data.B}"/>
```

where Data.B is an `EntitySet<B>`

Hope this helps.